# Robotium force stopping the application under test

Tags: android, robotium

I am using running a robotium test case using adb instrument command. After the test ends robotium is force stopping the application under tests. I understand that instrumentation and the application under test share the same process. My use case is that : I don't want to force stop the application under test for every robotoum test case execution. Is there a way to stop it?

This is what I see in adb logs:

```
03-01 15:12:15.318 I/TestRunner(13561): **passed: <Test name>**

03-01 15:12:15.318 W/InputManager(  728): Input event injection from pid 13561 permission denied.

03-01 15:12:15.338 I/ActivityManager(  728): Killing proc 13561:<**Packagename>**/u0a139: force stop

03-01 15:12:15.348 D/AndroidRuntime(13546): Shutting down VM
```

Answer (score 0):

`03-01 15:12:15.318 W/InputManager( 728): Input event injection from pid 13561 permission denied.` means that your app tries to inject events that it is not allowed to do. Either implement those features in your manifest or systemsign your app in case you have the platform key.

Comment: yeah there might be a problem with my App which is why it is getting permission denied. But do you think that is reason why it is force stopping the application under test?(next log statement).

Comment: How do you suggest to catch this error.I am not sending any input events from my test .. What might be the reasons for the issue? Does Handling exception in my test case work?

Comment: Please post the code so we can have a look at it. Exceptionhandling should help you.

Comment: My code is simple I have a base class that extends ActivityInstrumantationTestCase2. In the setup i create a new instance of solo and in the tear down i call solo.finishopenedActivities. I tried catch Throwable around the teardown and my test code. I still see that it is force stopping the app before and after test run

Comment: After commenting out solo.finishopenedActivities in tear down method i no longer see permission denied in my logs. But i see : 03-25 21:26:46.811 D/AndroidRuntime(10795): Shutting down VM

03-25 21:26:46.811 I/ActivityManager(  728): Killing proc 10811:<packagename>/u0a139: force stop

Comment: This is the android documentation:  http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html
The system classes load and start the test package, kill any processes that are running an instance of the application under test, and then load a new instance of the application under test. They then pass control to InstrumentationTestRunner, which runs each test case class in the test package. You can also control which test cases and methods are run using settings in Eclipse with ADT, or using flags with the command-line tools.

Answer (score 0):

Use Robotium with SinglelaunchActivityTestCase.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/SingleLaunchActivityTestCase.html

Comment: I tried using Robotium with SinglelaunchActivityTestCase but no luck. I see the force stopping of the app before the test case and after the test case. I really don't want to force stop the app under test. I should simulate the way  as we launch the app manually.

Comment: Please note i am running the tests by issuing adb commands from perl

Comment: i See the following lines in adb logs. 03-25 21:26:46.811 D/AndroidRuntime(10795): Shutting down VM
03-25 21:26:46.811 I/ActivityManager(  728): Killing proc 10811:<packagename>/u0a139: force stop

Comment: You should not use finishOpenedActivities in your tearDown(). Just do a super.tearDown(). It will only do a finish when the last test case is executed.

Comment: Even if i use super.teardown i see force stop of the app.I am running a single test using adb -shell am instrument -w -e class command issued through Perl. I don't want to force stop the app at all. Is that possible?

Comment: This is the android documentation: developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html The system classes load and start the test package, kill any processes that are running an instance of the application under test, and then load a new instance of the application under test. They then pass control to InstrumentationTestRunner, which runs each test case class in the test package. You can also control which test cases and methods are run using settings in Eclipse with ADT, or using flags with the command-line tools

Comment: Is there a way to stop the system classes force stopping the app under test?

Comment: Seeing a similar behavior, did you find a way??